# Download Zip File from Amazon S3 with Sinatra and AWS SDK for ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I am using the following code. I don't get any errors but the file doesn't download.

```
@bucket = @s3.buckets['bucket_name']
File.open('file_name.zip','wb') do |file|
    @bucket.objects['file_name.zip'].read do |chunk|
      file.write(chunk)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sure your `AWS.config` is setup with the proper keys and `file_name.zip` is spelled correctly? I can use this code with no issue locally, adding nothing more than `AWS.config(<my_config_options>)`

Comment: You are able to download a zip file to your computer from s3 using this code? It writes to the local folder the site is stored it but it does not initiate a download.

Comment: Yes. I replaced 'file_name.zip' with '/tmp/file_name.zip', but otherwise the implementation was exactly the same, with my own bucket and object names for 'bucket_name' and 'file_name.zip' of course.